# Spring MVC @SessionAttribute Missing session attribute of type String[] error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I was having some problem when trying to use @SessionAttribute in Spring MVC Controller. Basically what I am trying to do is, in my API, I want to retrieve from the session, if it contains data, fetch it out, then remove the session itself. Here is my controller class:

```
@SessionAttributes({WebKeys.SEARCH_RESULT_LIST_THREE})
public class ALController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search.do", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String doSearchList(Model model, @ModelAttribute("attendanceTO") AttendanceTO attendanceSearchForm, @SessionAttribute(WebKeys.SEARCH_RESULT_LIST_THREE) String[] selectedRecords) {
        // removed code

        attendanceSearchForm.setSelectedRecords(null);
        // checking from session
        if(selectedRecords != null && selectedRecords.length > 0){
            attendanceSearchForm.setSelectedRecords(selectedRecords);
        }
        model.addAttribute("selectedRecords", selectedRecords);
        // remove session
        model.addAttribute(WebKeys.SEARCH_RESULT_LIST_THREE, null);
    }
}
```

At this point of time, the session is not existed yet. I only set up the session when user submit form. I am getting this error messages:

```
Missing session attribute 'key.searchResultList.three' of type String[]
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should add a `required` parameter to the `@SessionAttribute` annotation and set its value to false,meaning it's not necessary,like

```
@SessionAttribute(name=WebKeys.SEARCH_RESULT_LIST_THREE,required=false)
```

Comment: Thanks! but let's say I got multiple SessionAttribute declared, how should I add it? As in I just wanted to SEARCH_RESULT_LIST_THREE set required to false

Comment: that depends on your situation,maybe you don't need to set all that param to false.

Comment: you can replace all the string `@SessionAttribute(` with `@SessionAttribute(required=false,name=` in your project ,just let the your IDE do the work